# My mongodb as primary replica set and mongodb atlas as secondary replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

I want to set mongodb replication architecture like the following. My own server as the primary replica set and mongodb atlas as the secondary replica set. Can this be done?
[replication architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Z3n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Please read the rest of the documentation (the picture of which you annotated) in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/ to fully understand how MongoDB replication works.

MongoDB Atlas is a Database-as-a-service, which runs self-contained MongoDB replica set. I believe what you are trying to do basically requires you to implement your own replication protocol.